# How to complete an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Suppose that 
 $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
        @. @. @. K\\
        @. @. @. @V\alpha VV \\
        0@>>>L @>{\phi}>>M @>{\psi}>>N @>>>0
    \end{CD} is a diagram of $R$-modules and homomorphisms whose row is exact. I want to show that one can turn this diagram into a commutative diagram with exact rows and exact columns of the following form 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
        @.@.0 @.0\\
        @. @. @VVV @VVV\\
        @.@. Ker \beta @>{\cong}>>Ker \alpha \\
        @.@.@VVV @VVV\\
        0@>>>L@>>>P@>>>K@>>>0\\
        @.@V{1_L}VV @V\beta VV @V\alpha VV \\
        0@>>>L @>{\phi}>>M @>{\psi}>>N @>>>0\\
        @. @. @VVV @VVV \\
        @. @. \frac{M}{Im \beta} @>{\cong}>> \frac{N}{Im \alpha} \\
        @. @. @VVV @VVV \\
        @. @. 0 @. 0 \\
        \end{CD} First, I want to know how to find such a $P$. I think it must be formed using both $Im \phi$ and $K$ but then I will face a problem on checking the commutativity. I would appreciate any hint or solution.

Comment: Using the [Four Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourLemma.html) you know that P must be isomorphic to K, and also that $\psi$ must be indeed an isomorphism.

Comment: So, I think that's not true in general, because you can choose $\psi$ in order not to be an isomorphism, and that would contradict the Four lemma.

Comment: @Javi $\psi$ is a previously given homomorphism and so it may be even not injective.

Comment: I know, that's why I think the result is not true in general, because exact columns with isomorphisms both on top and bottom imply that the other two morphisms are isomphisms.

Comment: @Javi the Four Lemma does not imply that $P$ and $K$ are isomorphic

Comment: @Javi The Four Lemma implies that the map $P\to K$ is surjective, but nothing forces it (nor $\psi$) to be injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Take $P$ to be the [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) $M\times_N K$ of $\psi$ and $\alpha$. In other words
$$P=\{(m,k)\in M\times K \mid \psi(m)=\alpha(k)\},$$
with maps $P\to M$ and $P\to K$ given by the restrictions of the two projections of $M\times K$. From there, it's easy to prove that the induced maps on the kernels must be isomorphisms, and for the cokernels you can use the Nine Lemma.

Comment: Thanks for your hint